# 'api.stackexchange.com/2.2/me' number of question and answers

Tags: support, feature-request

I was trying to fetch the number of answers I have posted on Stack Overflow and for that I was using this endpoint:

```
https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/me?site=stackoverflow
```

Check your own /me response [here](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/me).

It has all the relevant fields but not the number of questions and answers I have posted on Stack Overflow.

Any specific reason for not keeping it there, or does any other way (except paginating and counting all my answers from [/me/answers](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/me-answers)) exist to obtain that statistic?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to add a custom filter to include the `answer_count` and `question_count` fields.

This one:

> [`filter=!-*jbN*Cqbrcb`](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/me#order=desc&sort=reputation&filter=!-*jbN*Cqbrcb&site=stackoverflow&run=true)

will include those two fields.

You can find in the documentation for the [user](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/types/user) type which fields are included in the default filter (green-tick) and which not (red cross).

See my answer on Stack Apps [How to create API filters?](https://stackapps.com/questions/6815/how-to-create-api-filters/6908#6908) for instructions how to create a filter.